# Why does the second element have margin?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.logo a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.user {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.user a {
    color: white;
}
```

I have two div elements named logo and user.

I wish they have full height, but the user element seems to have non-zero `margin-top`.

Why does it happens and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please provide HTML code?

Comment: With `display: inline-block`, the bottom edges of child elements are aligned. Try using `vertical-align: top` on the children of the navbar's `div`. This should align the top edges, like you wanted.

Answer (score -2):

You should added selected styles  position: fixed; and  overflow: hidden;
 Like this.

```
>  .user {
>     display: inline-block;
>     border: 1px solid yellow;
>     position: fixed;
>     width: 100px;
>     overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: and what if the purpose is to have different font-size?

Comment: I changed description, Now we can use line-height, and all be ok.

Comment: Go to the duplicate link at the top of the question to learn why the OP as their issue.

Answer (score -2):

It is because of *display: inline-block;* which content default margin, to avoid margin use float:left in CSS

```
.logo {
    float:left
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.logo a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.user {
    float:left
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.user a {
    color: white;
}
```

**Or you can Check this helpful article for [Click here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)!**

Comment: Go to the duplicate link at the top of the question to learn why the OP as their issue.